# Will flex 4 work with flex 3 projects?

Tags: apache-flex

I can find a version of flex 3 since the release of flex 4. Will flex 4 work with my old project files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... it will work. Just import your Flex 3 projects into Flex 4.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flexbuilder3_to_flashbuilder4.html